# Python pandas pivot_table multiple time indices

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'T': [datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now()], 'V': [1, 2]})
```

I want to pivot using both the year and month as indices, which I can do as:

```
df.pivot_table(index = [df['T'].dt.year, df['T'].dt.month], values = 'V')
```

However, since that gives me two columns named `T`, I am unable to set `margins = True` (throws the error: `The name T occurs multiple times, use a level number`). How can I fix this issue? Ideally I would like to name the columns manually while doing the pivot, so that I have `Year`and `Month`instead of `T`and `T`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh that was easy, don't know what I was thinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `rename` to rename your series,

```
df.pivot_table(index = [df['T'].dt.year.rename('Year'),
                        df['T'].dt.month.rename('Month')], 
                values='V',
                aggfunc='sum', 
                margins=True)
```

Output:

```
              V
Year Month     
2020 1        3
All           3
```